# Must res.end() be called in express with node.js?

Tags: node.js, express

I have several [Express](http://expressjs.com/) applications, and I see that in some modules, [`res.end()`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.end) is called at the end of a request handler (after [`res.send`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.send) or [`res.json`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.json)), while in others, it isn't called.

For example:

```
app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Test', 200);
});
```

or:

```
app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Test', 200);
    res.end();
});
```

Both cases work, but I'm afraid about leaks or running out file descriptors or something like that, when I run many requests. Which one is "more correct"?

Comment: I thought `res.send()` triggered `res.end()` -- could be wrong tho.

Comment: @tymeJV You're right, it does: https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/lib/response.js#L154 ;)

Comment: Thank @Trevor-Senior, I was looking it that very same file and I didn't see it...

Comment: @greuze I've looked it up before so I had a head start :). I went ahead and moved the comment into a more structured answer for others.

Comment: Hi. And what about res.status(<any>).json(); And I have also another question. which error code should I send back if i am rejecting that call ? like user is exceeded his limit ?

Comment: One important thing to remember is that while both `res.send()` and `response.end()` will end the request Node will not terminate the process being handled until the end of the code block/method/function. If res.send()/end() is not the last thing in your method make sure to return it. For example: `return res.send();` will send a response AND terminate the script.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

The answer to your question is no. You don't have to call `res.end()` if you call `res.send()`. `res.send()` calls `res.end()` for you.

Taken from [/lib/response.js](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/4.3.1/lib/response.js#L166), here is the end of the `res.send()` function:

```js
  //. . .
  // respond
  this.end(head ? null : body);
  return this;
}
```

Comment: Maybe my memories finally getting better :)

Answer (score 12):

one example where you must call end() function is when you send buffer as a file to download.

```
res.write(buffer);
res.end();
```

Answer (score 6):

> `res.end([data] [, encoding])`

Ends the response process. This method actually comes from **Node core**, specifically the `response.end() method of http.ServerResponse.`
Use to quickly end the response without any data.

> If you need to respond with data, instead use methods such as
>   **`res.send() and res.json().`**