# Does Express.js on Node.js have a memory leak?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, memory-leaks

I have been using express on node.js running on a heroku server for a simple project. When I started using new relic to monitor the memory I noticed a slow memory leak pattern. I removed all the code I developed and all other node modules and left only express itself and new relic modules. I still observe the memory leak. 
I was wondering if this is express.js memory leak. 
[image: Here is the graphic from new relic]

Here is all the code left:

```
require('newrelic');
var express = require('express'); 
var app = express();
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
if ('development' == env) {
    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
}
app.get('/', function ( req, res ) {
    res.send('The server is up and running!');
});
app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log('Express server listening on port %d in %s mode', app.get('port'), app.get('env'));
});
```

And package.json

```
{
  "name": "memleakdebug",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.11.2",
    "newrelic": "^1.16.2"
  }
}
```

**UPDATE1:** Now growing memory even passed heroku's limit 512MB for free tiers.
Garbage collection doesn't seem to work.

[image: Memory keeps growing]

Comment: What you've shown is increasing memory usage, not necessarily a leak. You need to test what happens when the system is put under memory pressure. 350MB (the uppermost point in your graph) isn't a lot of memory use on modern systems; V8 may not have bothered to do any garbage collection (yet).

Comment: My original code was making a couple of hundreds of http requests and it was blowing the memory usage up to 1.5GB. Can you please give me a simple example and the memory limit that I can make V8 to do GC?

Comment: The simplest way is probably to give it less memory. I'm sure Heroku gives you control over that.

Comment: The smallest is 512MB I guess, I couldn't find a way to make it less.

Comment: Why do you `res.send` and not `res.end`? In the code, you seem to be leaving sockets open

Comment: @alandarev: Hmmm... Not clear whether you should use `.send` or `.end`. The simple example shown at the top of the [API page](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html) shows `.send`, and the [.end docs](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.end) say *"If you need to respond with data, instead use methods such as `res.send()` and `res.json()`."*

Comment: This link says send uses end. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20355280/3211198)

Comment: Ah, nevermind me then. I though expressjs `send` and `end` work same as for the *node.js socket*

Comment: It seems that the New Relic node.js agent has a memory leak.
See [Node.js Agent Memory Leak](https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/node-js-agent-memory-leak/9092)
 and 
[Memory leaking only with Node.js agent installed](https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/memory-leaking-only-with-node-js-agent-installed/14448)

Comment: try to use ``return res.send('The server is up and running!');``

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Lasse replied, there is a memory leak in New Relic.

https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/memory-leaking-only-with-node-js-agent-installed/14448

I experimented and removed

```
require('newrelic');
```

As you can see in the image below, since I removed the New Relic agent there is no more  memory leak.

[image]

Comment: Update - coleague is running Node.js + New Relic with no problems. We found the only significant difference to be that i'm running Node.js v0.12.x and he is running 0.10.x.

Can anyone confirm?

Comment: There was a large discussion on the [New Relic Community](https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/node-js-agent-memory-leak/9092/27) and a follow up post by them, passing the buck onto Node Core.  However updating the dependency to `1.24.x` appears to have resolved it (nothing else changing), at least per preliminary testing.  [Node0.12](https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/an-update-on-memory-management-in-node-js-perception-vs-reality/31934) did consistently use higher amounts of memory.

Comment: Thx @nerdwaller good to know. I'll report back when I do a new experiment.

Comment: After a full day of run it still was increasing for me, though at a significantly reduced rate.  I just deployed a version without the new relic agent to compare - I will try to report back what I see!  For comparison sake I am using `Node v0.10.36` and `New Relic v1.24.x` for the tests.

Comment: Confirmed without the new relic package our memory holds steady. It should allow us to have a few workers per dyno saving a bit of cash. Probably going to ditch new relic for now.