# Can I delay PUT upload in Express until my server finishes an operation?

Tags: http, express, browser, amazon-s3

I have a server that receives files via PUT and in turn stores them in S3.

After a client PUTs files it will usually request them right in return for rendering. Unfortunately my server takes a bit of time to actually process the upload and store them in S3.

Here is the code I use in Express:

```js
    req.pipe(writeStream);

    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');


    if ('OPTIONS' === req.method) {
        res.sendStatus(200);
        res.end('OK!');
        return;
    }

    if ('PUT' === req.method) {

        writeStream.on('error', () => {
            res.sendStatus(500);
        });

        writeStream.on('close', async () => {
            // This might take 30s
            await this.storage.store(fn, args.blobID);

            // This does not seem to have any effect
            // I would like to prevent the client from 'finishing' the
            // PUT request before I say it is done.
            res.end('OK!')
        });

        res.sendStatus(200);
    }
```

Ideally I could 'stall' my client's PUT request for until `storage.store()` completed, making sure the file is actually available.

Is there any way how I could do this?

Also, I am not sure about the `sendStatus()` / `end()` calls, feel free to comment if I mixed something up.

P.S. I know, in an ideal world I would just hand out signed URLs and let the client upload to S3 directly, but I need AES256 encryption ...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with S3 uploading, but I guess that there will be a callback(such as sending back a response(success or fail... etc) to you). (If not, please tell me)

```
S3.upload(data,function(response){ // something like this
  // then, you can callback
  // ...
  // res.end() or res.sendStatus(...)
})
```

As I remember it, Express don't send timeout automatically, so you just put response in the S3's response function, so that your request should not end until your storing end.

> From [Must res.end() be called in express with node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20355136/must-res-end-be-called-in-express-with-node-js)
>
> You don't have to call res.end() if you call res.send(). res.send() calls res.end() for you.

and res.sendStatus() equals to res.status(...).send(message or code) (via http://expressjs.com/en/api.html)

So, res.sendStatus() will call end().

Comment: Thanks. However, I seem to have to call `res.sendStatus(200);` to trigger the actual client upload. Also, the store function is `async` and will wait for the S3 upload to finish.