# Can't get Node mssql to work properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-mssql

This is the way I'm using mssql at the moment but it gives sometimes errors:

JavaScript:

```
router.get('/academiejaren', (req, res) => {
    sql.connect(dbconfig, function (err) {
        var request = new sql.Request();
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        request.query("SELECT * FROM [Alg].[DefAJ];", function (err, recordset) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return;
            }
            else {
                res.end(JSON.stringify(recordset));
            }
        });
        request.query();
    });
});
```

Error:

```
{ ConnectionError: Connection is closed.
    at C:\Users\Milan\Documents\Octopus\Octopus 2.0\node_modules\mssql\lib\main.js:1569:17
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
  name: 'ConnectionError',
  message: 'Connection is closed.',
  code: 'ECONNCLOSED' }
(node:556) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): ConnectionError: Connection is closed.
(node:556) DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I'm using version 3.2.0 because I can't get the newest one, 4.0.2, to work... Any help or some good examples, because I can't figure out the documentation...

thank in advance!

**EDIT**

Updated on a small test project to 4.0.2. and I got it to work. Going to change my API to this update.

```
router.get('/academiejaren', (req, res) => {
    (async function () {
        try {
            let pool = await sql.connect(config)
            let result1 = await pool.request()
                .query('SELECT * FROM [Alg].[DefAJ];')

            res.send(JSON.stringify(result1.recordset));


        } catch (err) {
            res.send("CAUGHT ERROR academiejaren");
        }
    })()

    sql.on('error', err => {
        // ... error handler
    })
});
```

Now I do have a small question left, what should I do with the catch and sql.on()? How should I handle error's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
router.get('/academiejaren', (req, res) => {
    sql.connect(dbconfig, function (err) {
        var request = new sql.Request();
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        request.query("SELECT * FROM [Alg].[DefAJ];", function (err, recordset) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return;
            }
            else {
                res.send(JSON.stringify(recordset));
            }
        });
        request.query();
    });
});
```

you literally did `res.end`, `end` exits it, you want `res.send`

Comment: Ow god... But it did work sometimes? I got my data back from the api? It just sometimes gave back this error?

Comment: you opened the connection. Nothing wrong with that part and if you want to know more about res.end look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40326333/7707749

Comment: Oh, okay thanks!! I have one question if I may? Do I have to sql.close() after every data manipulation/download?

Comment: No need for a close of the sql, the res.send exits it for you I think? you'd have to look that up, but the sql doesn't need a `close`

Comment: and geen probleem ;P

Comment: I'll look it up! Thanks! België of Nederland? ;D

Comment: I keep clicking that chat button xD and Nederland

Answer (score 1):

I do it a little bit different:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

    sql.connect(dbconfig).then(function() {
            // Query 
            new sql.Request().query("Your query")
              .then(function(recordset) {
                //console.dir(recordset);
                res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                res.send( recordset );
              }).catch(function(err) {
                // ... query error checks 
            });
       });
  });
```

Now in your dbconfig make sure you got it like:
**mssql://user:password@server/db**

Comment: Yes, I found a lot of different approaches. See the edit I'm going to make, now I'm using an async function. That's what I found in de documentation.