# mssql node, get request returns ReferenceError: request is not defined

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js, express

working on rest api for my db got this problem

> ReferenceError: request is not defined

right now I have a connection that works, but stuck with how to make rest requests with mssql-node. originally I used mySql db but now have to make it work with mssql. after I spent some time I have 2 error types - this one or connection doesn't work if I do connection in app.get

the way it's set up right now is

```
const express = require('express')
const sql = require('mssql');
const Connection = require('tedious').Connection;

var config = {
  userName: 'user' , 
  password: 'pass', 
  domain: "AD",
  server: serversIP,
  database: 'test',
  port: 2222,
  debug: true,
  driver: 'tedious',
  options: {
    database:"test",
    instanceName : "instance"
  } 
}
var connection = new Connection(config);
connection.on('connect', function(err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log("server is connected to DB")
      }}
 );

app.get("/" , (req, res)=>{
    new sql.Request().query(`SELECT * FROM test `, (err, recordset) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
        }
      else {
        res.send(JSON.stringify(recordset));
        }
      });
    request.query();
    });
```

what can be the reason for this error?

UPDATE

after several small iterations of errors I got an error that connaction isn't specified

with new function like this

```
app.get("/getUsers", (req, res)=>{
  sql.connect(config, function (err) {
    var request = new sql.Request();
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }
  new sql.query(`SELECT * FROM dbo.tblDatabaseUserIDs_lookup `, (err, recordset) => {
    console.log("first error msg");
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return;
      }
    else {
      console.log("second error msg");
      res.send(JSON.stringify(recordset));
      }
    });
    console.log("3rd error msg");
  //req.query();
  });
});
```

my new error msg is

> var bufferLength = 64 + domain.length * 2 + username.length * 2 + lm
>   v2len + ntlmv2len + 8 + 8 + 8 + 4 + server_data.length + 4;
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

thought that it can be due to first connection function so i replaced

```
  sql.connect(config, function (err) {
    var request = new sql.Request();
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }
```

with

```
...connection.callProcedure(function (err) {
    new sql.query(`SELECT * ....
```

and got this

> TypeError: request.validateParameters is not a function

but with

```
 connection.commitTransaction
```

it gives me this one

> (node:15956) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection (rejection id: 1): RequestError: No connection  is specified
>   for that request.

the fun part that i tried to follow this solution [Can't get Node mssql to work properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43609427/cant-get-node-mssql-to-work-properly)

Comment: try `sql.query` instead of `sql.Request().query`

Comment: @mugiseyebrows , same result

Comment: Oh, I see. There is `request.query();` on line before last line which is in fact not defined.

Comment: @mugiseyebrows, I don't know how to make it right. should it be something like  -  var request = new express.Request(); ? I tried it and it didn't work for me neither

Comment: Just remove it. It doesn't do anything (I guess, I'm not sure why you add it).

Comment: @mugiseyebrows I tried it and made an update to original post with a new errors after i tried to fix them too, still jumping from one to another

Answer (score 1):

This may help!! 
try to pass connection as an argument for Request().
`var request = new sql.Request(connection)`

[a link](https://github.com/tediousjs/node-mssql/issues/383)