# Why does the webpage load forever if there is a 404?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express, heroku

I have an Express.js/Node.js website hosted with Heroku. If a file can't be found, the server is supposed to send a 404 error (like most websites do). But the error handlers in my code don't work properly. When the client requests a file that doesn't exist, the page will load...and load...and load...forever. How do I make the server stop loading when it detects the file can't be found?

This is the first section of my JavaScript:

```
var express = require('express'); // Express.js
var app = express();
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(app);
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var postgres = require('pg'); // Postgres database

app.use(express.static('static', {
    extensions: ['html']
}));

app.all('*', function (request, response, next) {
    var redirectURL = request.query.redirect;
      if (redirectURL != undefined) {
        response.redirect(redirectURL);
      }
});

app.get('/', function (request, response, next) {
  response.redirect('/main/index');
});
```

And the following is my error handling middleware (it goes right after the previous part). The first one handles 400x error codes and the second one handles 500x error codes.

```
// Handle 404 error
app.use(function(request, response) {
    response.status(400);
    response.send("Error 404!");
});

// Handle 500 error
app.use(function(error, request, response, next) {
    response.status(500);
    response.send("Error 500!");
});

server.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, function () {
  console.log('Listening on port 8080!');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call response.end() in your middleware, like so

```
// Handle 404 error
app.use(function(request, response) {
    response.status(400);
    response.send("Error 404!");
    response.end();
});
```

This is how I check for errors in my app, one single middleware

```
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
            if (err.statusCode === 403) {
                res.statusCode = 403;
                var out = {
                    message: 'missing/invalid authorization: ' + err.message,
                    code: err.code,
                    statusCode: err.statusCode
                };
                res.end(JSON.stringify(out));
                return;
            }
            next(err);
        });
```

- Check that your middleware actually gets called, console.log should be sufficient
- If a middleware does not end the request, it must forward the request to the next middleware, so you need to call next(), the format of a middleware is

  app.use((req, res, next) => {
    //I'm not doing anything, forward the request
    next();
  });

  app.use((req, res, next) => {
      req.send('I ended the request');
      //this middleware ended the request
  }));

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. Calling `res.end()` at the end of the error handler has no effect. And according to this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20355136/must-res-end-be-called-in-express-with-node-js) calling `res.send()` already calls `res.end()` automatically. What else could be causing the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I had almost the same issue (in my case it was the page for HTTP 500 that was loading forever) and the problem was with another middleware that I have added myself and which was before the error handler middlewares and inside which **I forgot to call `next()`**:

```
app.use(function(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
  closeConnFromRequestStorage()
  next(); // make sure to call to call next
});
```