# NodeJs app "hanging" or "freezing" whenever an error occurs

Tags: javascript, node.js, server

When I make multiple post requests to my nodejs server and all of the parameters are correct, everything works fine (and doesnt freeze) but when I make multiple post requests with incorrect parameters that gives an error, my nodejs server just freezes/hangs for a few minutes. Why is this?

Here is my code btw

```
app.post('/pushtransaction', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(5);
    if (req.body.sigs) {
        let sigver = xmf.modules.ecc.Signature.from(req.body.sigs).toString();
        let lasig = [sigver];
        console.log(req.body.packedTr);
        let transi = JSON.parse(req.body.packedTr);

        //let sigver = req.body.sigs;
        let package = {
            compression: 'none',
            transaction: transi,
            signatures: lasig
        }

        console.log(package);
        //Pushes tx in correct format
        xmf.pushTransaction(package).then(result=>{
            res.send(result);
            res.end();
            console.log(result);
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        });
    }
})
```

Comment: How many times are you making "multiple post requests". Javascript naturally processes errors slower than error free code, so that may be part of the problem.

Answer (score 4):

When your error is encountered, your Node server does not know what to do other than `console.log()` the error. It needs to end that request and send some response. You can `res.status(400).send({ error: err })` when you're within the catch.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `res.send()` method gets called every time in your request.

Updated Javascript:

```
app.post('/pushtransaction', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(5);
    if (req.body.sigs) {
        let sigver = xmf.modules.ecc.Signature.from(req.body.sigs).toString();
        let lasig = [sigver];
        console.log(req.body.packedTr);
        let transi = JSON.parse(req.body.packedTr);

        //let sigver = req.body.sigs;
        let package = {
            compression: 'none',
            transaction: transi,
            signatures: lasig
        }

        console.log(package);
        //Pushes tx in correct format
        xmf.pushTransaction(package).then(result=>{
            res.send(result);
            res.end();
            console.log(result);
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(400).send();
        });
    }

    res.status(400).send();
})
```

Additionally you don't have to call `res.end()` if you call `res.send()`. see [Must res.end() be called in express with node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20355136/must-res-end-be-called-in-express-with-node-js)

Answer (score 0):

Adding to other answers, you can add a middleware for timeouts, if any service fails to respond in some time, like

```
var timeout = require('connect-timeout');
app.use(timeout('5s'));
```